# after_update callback in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I am trying to create a task by using attributes of the customer bill and given below are the

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
 after_update :updating_daily_job_task

def updating_daily_job_task
  if self.amount.present? && self.date.present?
  Task.create(:name => self.supplier_id.to_s, :due => self.date)
end
end
end
```

task model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :due, :complete, :user_id, :supplier_bill_id
  belongs_to :supplier_bill, :foreign_key => "supplier_bill_id"

  validates_presence_of :name, :due
end
```

and i am getting the following error

> undefined method `create' for Rake::Task:Class

can anyone tell me where i am doing anything wrong??? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the class name for the `Task` model. Change it to `SupplierTask` or anything more relavant. Task is used somewhere in Rails internals, which causes this issue.

Comment: Yes, [`Task`](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words/) is reserved word in Rails. The solution is to change the name of your model.

Comment: yes i changes the name of task now it is working fine. Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this one but it looks like when you reference the Task class you're picking up the wrong class (you're getting the one from the Rake module).  You could try changing the name of your task model and see whether that removes the clash